# What's the difference between "int *a[5]" and int(*a)[5]"?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

Would they work differently on C and C++?

Comment: One of the key points in the answers in the previous thread is to note that int (*a)[5] could be a pointer to the first row of a matrix that has 5 integers per row, so that a[0] points to the first row, a[1] points to the second row, ... .

Answer (score 17):

1. `int *a[5] -` 
   It means that "a" is an array of pointers i.e. each member in the array "a" is a pointer
   of type integer; Each member of the array can hold the address of an integer.
2. `int (*a)[5] -` 
   Here "a" is a pointer to the array of 5 integers, in other words
   "a" points to an array that holds 5 integers.

Example :

```
#include<stdio.h>
   int main()
   {
           int b = 3;
           int c = 4;
           int *a[2] = {&b, &c}; // is same as ---int *a[] = {&b, &c} 
           printf("value pointed to by a[0] = %d, by a[1] = %d\n", *a[0], *a[1]);
           return 0;
   }
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes, theres a huge difference. Let see some code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int *a[5]; // same as: int *(a[5]);
    int(*b)[5];

    printf("*a[5] vs (*b)[5] : %d vs %d", sizeof (a), sizeof(b));
    // *a[5] vs (*b)[5] : 20 vs 4
}
```

What does that mean?

First case (**int *a[5]**) is **array of 5 pointers to int**

and second (**int(*b)[5]**) is **pointer to array of 5 ints**.

The difference makes here **()**.

And yes, the behavior is same in C and C++.

Answer (score 6):

This is an array of 5 pointers to int:

```
int* a[5];
```

This is a pointer to an array of 5 ints:

```
int (*a)[5];
```

Here's an example of how you could initialize the pointer or the elements of the array of pointers:

```
int a[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
int (*p)[5]; // pointer to array of 5 ints
int* b[5];   // array of 5 pointers to int

p = &a; // p points to a

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
  std::cout << (*p)[i] << " ";
std::cout << std::endl;

// make each element of b point to an element of a
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
  b[i] = &a[4-i];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
  std::cout << b[i] << " ";
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Note that although I have used C++ in the example, this applies to C and C++.

Comment: Could you initialise it and give an example how the accessing of elements would work please? (I hope this is the way to reply to an answer :) )

Comment: @RaghavSharma `int* a[5]; int* b=a[0]; int b[5]; int (*c)[5]=&b; int y=(*c)[0]`

Comment: @RaghavSharma I added an example

Comment: @RaghavSharma :  #include<stdio.h>
   int main()
   {
           int b = 3;
           int c = 4;
           int *a[2] = {&b, &c};
           printf("value pointed to by a[0] = %d, by a[1] = %d\n",  *a[0], *a[1]);
           return 0;
   }

Comment: Thanks all :) 
@juanchopanza ok thanky you :)

Comment: In the above example, for pointer `p`, can we let it point to array of size greater than 5 or is it restricted to only size 5 throughout the whole program?

Answer (score 6):

`int* a[5]` declare `a` as array 5 of pointer to int

`int (*a)[5]` declare `a` as pointer to array 5 of int

I suggest you to use [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) to understand such or any complex declarations.

Comment: cdecl is something new! Thank you :)