# Difference between (*)[] and *[] declarations

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

*EDIT*
I've read the question and answers here: ***[C pointer to array/array of pointers disambiguation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation)***.  The answers there do not address the focus of my questions here as well as some of the answers already posted below.  This is *similar*, but not a *duplicate*.  The focus here is intended to be centered around explaining how the `()` changes the declaration. The focus in the link is broader, and in fact does not center around the impact and effect of `()` on a declaration such as the ones I include below.

What is the reason for the difference in the way

1. `int *a[5];`
2. `int (*a)[5];`

are created?

*I am particularly interested in an explanation of how the `()` changes the declaration*.

*For example*:

With 1)

```
a[0] = malloc(sizeof(int)); //compiles
```

But with 2) it does not.  ( *error: array type int [5] is not assignable* )
***Questions:***
1) What is the effect of the `()` in `2)`?
2) Why would declaration `2` ever be used over declaration 1?
(that is, why would declaration `2` ever be used?)

Comment: Check here http://cdecl.org/

Comment: @machine_1 - reference is close, I am also asking explicitly for insights on what the effect of `()` are on the declarations.

Comment: It's not extremely unique compared to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25790789/whats-the-difference-between-int-a5-and-inta5?lq=1 (and others)

Comment: @BoPersson - that link, by one level of indirection, points to precisely the same link I referred to above.  But thanks.

Comment: @R Sahu - Please see my edit above.

Comment: It is a duplicate still. The () makes it a different type - an array pointer, instead of an array of pointers. Basically you are just asking "what is an array pointer", a question that has been answered many times before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `int (*a)[5];`, `()` binds `*` to `a` and declare it as a pointer to an array. In `int *a[5];`, `a` binds to operator `[]` due to higher precedence than `*` and therefore declare it as an array of pointers.

So, in second case `a` is a pointer to an array and `a[0]` is an array (of type `int [5]`) and as per C rule arrays are not assignable. That's make the statement

```
a[0] = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

illegal.

Comment: This addresses my question directly.  I understand your explanation.  Thank you.

Comment: Why would anyone choose to use the second declaration type?  `(*a)[5];`  What purpose would there be to create this variable?

Comment: This kind of declaration often used as function parameter where a 2D array is passed to a function.

Comment: Operator precedence has no relevance in a declaration. The declaration syntax is merely similar to some C operators.

Comment: @Lundin can you explain it further?

Comment: Nothing in the expression is an operator. The `()` is a special form of declaration described in 6.7.6.1/6: "If, in the declaration ‘‘T D1’’, D1 has the form ( D ) then _ident_ has the type specified by the declaration ‘‘T D’’. Thus, a declarator in parentheses is identical to the unparenthesized declarator, but the binding of complicated declarators may be altered by parentheses."  Similarly, the `[]` is an array declaration, not an operator.

Answer (score 5):

They are not the same, rather quite different.

1. `int *a[5];` is an array of 5 `int *`s.
2. `int (*a)[5];` is a pointer to an array of 5 `int`s.

So, in the former case, `a[0]` is a pointer variable, hence, you can assign. But in the later, `a[0]` is an array type, and is not assignable, by definition.

---

Edit:

In case you're interested in the difference of type due to the presence of the `()`, have a look at the [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). The `[]` has higher precedence over the `*`, so without an explicit `()`, the attachment of `a` goes to `[]` first.

Comment: So, with `2`, a[0] does not exist, while with `1` it does?

Comment: @ryyker; `a[0]` exists for both cases. When you declare a pointer `int i; int *p = &i;` then `p` is actually a pointer pointing to the first element of an array of length `1` and that element can be accessed either by `*p` or `p[0]`.

Comment: @ryyker `a[0]` anyways _exist_, in both the scenarios.

Comment: Operator precedence has nothing to do with declarations. There are no operators in either of those rows.

Answer (score 2):

Because `1` is an array of pointers, while 2 is a pointer to an array of 5 `int`. Check like this

```
int (*a)[5];
int *b[5];

fprintf(stderr, "%zu\n", sizeof(a)); // Prints sizeof(void *)
fprintf(stderr, "%zu\n", sizeof(b)); // Prints 5 * sizeof(void *)
```

Answer (score 2):

This

```
int *a[5];
```

is a declaration of an array of 5 pointers of type `int *`.

So `a[0]` is an object of type `int *` and you may initialize it with a pojnter of type `void * in C

```
a[0] = malloc(sizeof(int)); //compiles
```

This`

```
int (*a)[5];
```

is a declaration of a pointer to an object of type `int[5]`. So `a[0]` is an array of 5 elements of type `int` . You may not assign an array with a pointer,

Thus this statement

```
a[0] = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

is invalid.

Comment: @SouravGhosh It is a typo as result of copy and paste.:)